# footer special shape for all desktop resolutions

Tags: html, css, sass, footer, pseudo-element

I've created my own footer design and I'm busy implementing it. The issue I have at the moment is with the darker sides of the footer at the right and at the left, as you can see in the image. I play with transparencies and try to create those diagonal shapes. I've created these forms using `:before` and `:after` status. The footer content needs to be wrapped in a wrapper of `1024px`. The problem resides on that point...

The darker sides should fill up the 100% of the width for each side. The middle part has the same color but with a different opacity level. I've tried different techniques with no results
I'm a bit stuck.

Image 1 is the desired effect.

Image 2 is the problem I get with my actual code. If the screen gets bigger than `1024px` it's displayed this way.

I'm trying to maintain the HTML5 markup as clean as possible and rely on the CSS for the work.
Do you have any suggestions?

IMAGE 1:
[image]

IMAGE 2:

[image]

HTML5 markup:

```
 <footer>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <aside class="contact-details">
                    <span>Email:
                        <a href="mailto:mail">info@lorem.com</a>
                    </span>
                    <span>Tel:
                        <a href="tel:WAITING FOR OFFICAL PHONE">786 - 520 - 482</a>
                    </span>
                </aside>

                <aside class="company-details">
                    <span>2013 lorem lorem</span>
                    <h1>LOREM LOREM LOREM</h1>
                </aside>

                <aside class="social-details">
                    <span class="visitors">Visitors: 98131</span>
                    <ul>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sprites-facebook ir">facebook</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sprites-twitter ir">twitter</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sprites-googleplus ir">google plus</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sprites-linkedin ir">linkedin</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sprites-youtube ir">youtube</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

This is my SASS:

```
footer{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(140,137,121,0.85);
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    font-size: 14px;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(rgba(37,36,37,0.2), rgba(45,44,45,0.2)));

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 0 0 5px;

        &:link,&:visited{
            color: #cfcfcf;
        }

        &:hover{
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        &:active{
            color: rgba(247,51,117,0.8);
        }
    }
}

aside{
        float: left;
        position: relative;

    &.contact-details{

        &:before{
            position: absolute;
            right: -7px;
            border-top: 30px solid rgba(38,37,38,0.75);
            border-right: 30px solid transparent;
            z-index: -1;

            // @include background-image(linear-gradient(rgba(37,36,37,0.75), rgba(45,44,45,0.75)));
            content: "";
        }

        &:after{
            position: absolute;
            right: 23px;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(38,37,38,0.75);
            z-index: -1;
            content: "";
        }
    }

    &.contact-details,&.social-details{

        span{
            float: left;
            margin: 4px 20px 0 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: #cfcfcf;
        }
    }

    ul{
        float: left;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;

        li{
            list-style: none;
            display: inline;

            a{
                float: left;
                margin: 0 15px 0 0;
                padding: 0;
                @include box-shadow(rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 2px 2px 5px);

                &:link,&:visited{
                    opacity: 0.8;
                }

                &:hover,&:active{
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.company-details{
        width: 293px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        span{
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        h1{
            width: 232px;
            font-family: telegrafico, serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #262526;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(64,64,64,0.3);
            background-color: rgba(242,242,242,0.3);
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 60px;

            &:before{
                border-bottom: 38px solid rgba(242,242,242,0.3);
                border-left: 38px solid transparent;
                content:"";
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: -38px;
            }

            &:after{
                border-bottom: 38px solid rgba(242,242,242,0.3);
                border-right: 38px solid transparent;
                content:"";
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: -38px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```